# how to compare signatures?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, signature

[image]
[image]

```
     **SIGNATURE 1**                       **SIGNATURE 2**
```

**How do I compare both signatures, I've tried Harris Corner detection but the results weren't satisfactory. I'm new to image-processing, please guide me.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The oldest Machine Learning technique is from Bromley et. al. in 1993: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/2987189.2987282

you could try and reproduce this.